# Add quote markup to comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, blockquote, markdown

Comments have a very restricted markup ability.  Currently supported text markups available are

- *Italic text*
- **Bold text**
- `code`

One of the very common things people do in comments that is *not supported* is **quoting other people's text**.  It is very natural to highlight what someone else has said to add more context to your comment.

The problem is that you cannot specify text is a quote via markup.  Commonly people will use one of the previously mentioned methods to highlight text as being a quote.  I find myself using the code markup to distinguish quotes from *italic* and **bold text**.  And, frankly, it's weird.

Can we have an addition to the currently supported set of comment markup for quotes?

> Perhaps mimicking the style of quote text in posts for each site?

Here's a mockup:

[image: Mockup for the ... for Tim Stone]

Comment: Yeah... big, full-featured comments with a `more...` link would be nice too.

Comment: @minitech: Seems like it would hide important information, thus going against the mantra "comments are not where important stuff goes."

Comment: "comments that is *not supported* is **quoting other people's text**" - LIES! But I might be swayed by a free-hand drawing of what this would look like, given the space constraints...

Comment: @TimStone: Its hard to freehand circle a background color change, but I did add a mockup for you.

Comment: "One of the very common things people do in comments that is not supported is **quoting other people's text.**" What's wrong with... dah, dah, DAAAH, ...quotation marks? ;)

Comment: Nice, but then: would there be any standard Markdown element available, and could that then also be used for inline quotations in regular posts? Too bad [Markdown does not specify `<q>`](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax). (Note that using `<cite>` [would be wrong](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-cite-element).)

Comment: `BACKTICKS FOR QUOTES IN COMMENTS`

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: That's `for code`.  Its weird to be using code markup for quotes.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn and it might confuse those that are trying to quickly find code--bots like ohloh, as well as human readers on copy-paste autopilot.

Comment: After 3 years, still we don't have quotes in comments!

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Please don't: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/7437/88

Comment: @Tobias Kienzler: Please. I'm the last person who'd endorse them. That hasn't changed in over four years.

Comment: Is everybody seriously spectacularly missing the sarcastic tone of my comment from over four years ago? Look all around you. How often do you see people using backticks for quotations in comments? Even those who oppose their use for highlighting keywords and the like in proper posts do it in comments anyway. Why don't you go and ask them why they do that?

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Great, now we need sarcasm-markup (sarcup) as well... You could have added quadruple exclamation marks ;) Anyway, I felt a link to anyone taking you _serious_ were in order

Comment: @Arashsoft  Infact, it's now 5 years, and there isn't even a status tag issued by a mod yet. So, have they declined or accepted this idea?

Comment: Incredible, how many more people will come here and find this!

Comment: What about just hightlighting with `<mark>`? If it was supported. [Add <mark> support, or other text highlighting method](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/318533/148486).

Comment: @user1228 I voted up your comment as I mostly agree. However, I will note that, anymore, site rules, and even site goals, are wildly different from site to site. Although I'm sure this wasn't intended, I believe that it gives each community it's own character, and adds a great deal of charm to SE overall. I don't see how adding _the_ _ability_ (determined per-site) to enhance the markup could do anything but add to that charm. For me, joining a new SE community and learning the quirks is the funnest part of the SE experience. Thoughts?

Comment: Keep in mind, I'm not referring to sites like SO, where the changes obviously wouldn't be implemented. I'm referring mostly to some of the newer "Fringe" sites. Although there are a few mid-sized ones that I could see benefiting.

Answer (score -1):

A simple permanent workaround is, to use browser extensions, like e.g. [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) or [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/), to automatically replace quotation marks in comments with the appropriate HTML `<span class="quote">…</span>` and add an easily customizable style for it. (Or just `<span style="background-color: #AAA">…</span>` to save installing Stylish.)

Please remember to include all quotes. Legacy substituts like `"` and `'`, real English ones like `“` and `”` plus `‘` and `’`, and real ones for your language, like e.g. `„` and `“` plus `»` and `«` for German

Of course it won’t be visible for others, but if it matters to them, they will end up here and install it themselves too.

Comment: (Never forget, that you are not obliged to display HTML in any specific way, and don’t even need to display it at all. It is YOUR computer. Hence why demands to display ads just because they are referenced in the HTML are so silly. If they wanted to put conditions on what they serve you, they shouldn’t have instructed their web server, to send anyone that data upon a mere request unless those conditions are met.)