# How should I cite other users' text in comments, since blockquotes don't compile as they would in the question-field?

Tags: support, comments

I have posted a question on CS SE and below this kind user's [answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/145325/how-does-the-inorder-tree-walk-algorithm-move-to-a-different-node-after-hitting/145330#145330) I have posted a comment where I am trying to cite their text to refer to it using the `>` character (in a blockquote) like so:

> Here an example of cited text

In the question or answer fields this compiles nicely, in the comments section however, it does not.

How should I go about citing sentences in comments below answers or questions?

Comment: FR: [Add quote markup to comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120031/1017231). Note that [using backticks/code markup is bad](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135112/inline-code-spans-should-not-be-used-for-emphasis-right)

Comment: Related: https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6991/246019 https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1085/246019

Comment: I would prefer like-As said by Ilam "In the question or answer fields this compiles nicely, in the comments section however, it does not."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cite the text inside "double" or 'single' quotes. *Italics* are ok too. Or a combination of the above for complex cases, such as:
When you say 'your "stuff" does not work', do you mean it *does not work* any more, or that it had never "worked"?

Comment: I always use `_“The quote by the other user”_ — My reply to that quote.` or something similar.

Comment: @TimurShtatland I have edited the title of the question to clarify: "How should I cite other users' text in comments, since blockquotes don't compile as they would in the question-field?"

Comment: @ilamengl Thank you for letting me know! Updated the answer.